# How to write ' using LaTeX in python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, latex, symbols

I tried:

```
plt.text(0.29, 0.06, r'$R_k'$')
plt.text(0.29, 0.06, r'$R_k\prime$')
```

The first is an error and the second gives very big bold prime.

Answer (score 3):

What is the ultimate wording you want to achieve?

Have you tried `\textsc{\char13}` as this is the character code for `´`?

```
plt.text(0.29, 0.06, r'$R_k \textsc{\char13}$')
```